# Sending notification on macOS from CLI application in C++

Tags: c++, macos, notifications

I have a small automatic download application, written in C++, for a system I am developing and I need to send a notification when the file download is complete.

The application needs to be corss-platfrom. I have with system specific code for windows and linux for sending notifications which work. Now I need for macOS.

However, I have not been able to find a way to do this from C++ without using QT, which I am not interested in. 
Is it really true that I cannot call the system libraries for this without objective-c?

Comment: You are probably going to have to use `#ifdef _WIN32` , `#ifdef _WIN64`
`#if __APPLE__` and `#if __linux__` and wrtie specific code for each OS

Comment: There is no standard C++ API for sending notifications. So you’ll either need to find a third party library that is cross-platform or use macros as suggested by Clonk above.

Comment: I have updated the question